# Power BI Line in Column Chart is lower the Legend

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

In my "Line and stacked column chart" the line is lower the the values on the legend:
[image]

My *SOLL* value should be by far higher then the *Plan* value:
[image]

The Tooltip even tells me that the number is higher.

This is how the chart is set up:
[image]

Unti now I was using this chart just like this for other Values and it worked just fine:
[image]

Behaviour: Power BI pics the Values form the X-Axis to create an automated MAX for the Range of the Y-Axis.
**Solution** (*Thank you Peter*): **Create a Mesure that gives the bigger value and us it as the MAX for the Y-Axis ragne.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Columns are drawn on the (primary) y-axis, the line is drawn on the secondary y-axis.
In the formatting pane you have to temporarily enable the secondary y-axis, which allows you to set the **Range** to that of the primary y-axis. At least make sure to set **Align zeros** to **On**. Afterwards you can disable the axis again. The settings will be kept.

Comment: I do not understand your suggestion fully but you are on the right way.
If I put a max on Y-Rage greater then my SOLL it looks fine. But if I put it back to Auto, it looks as bad as before.

Comment: I hope YOU are on the right way. Was my answer helpful to solve YOUR problem?

Comment: If I put the range to a max of 100.000 it works just fine. But then I can not set it back on "Auto" otherwhise it does not work proper any more.

Comment: I have made a mesure that pics the bigger value SOLL vs PLAN und this is the MAX for my Range. Thank you!